# how do i create table in mysql cluster using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am using the hibernate with spring boot and table created in given database but not in another database like 10.10.1.350 is management node and 10.10.1.348 and 10.10.1.349 are child db. when we create table using query directly in 348 then table auto created in 349. But we are using the hibernate then table created in 348 but not auto create in 349.

Properties like:-

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://10.10.1.348:3306/test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=abc@1234
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Pojo Class-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Test {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "tst_id")
    private Long tstId;
    @Column(name = "tst_nm")
    private String tstNm;


}
```

pom.xml for mysql dependency-

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate docs says](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#best-practices-schema):

> Although Hibernate provides the `update` option for the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` configuration property, this feature is not suitable for a production environment.

Just use Flyway or Liquibase for DB migrations. [Spring boot integrates with both of them](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool).

Comment: hi @luboskrnac,there is no way to createtables in ndb cluster by hibernate automatically?wwe have to run mysql creeate table query?

Comment: As I mentioned, there are dedicated tools for doing database migration. Check Liquibase or Flyway.

Comment: yes i got it,the answer was for 4 years ago and i wanted to know is there any updates or not.but it seems i have to use dedicated  tools .thank you very much